# Timestamp in R Studio

Tags: r

n R studio how do you Convert the timestamp column to dates using the `lubridate::as_datetime` function?

```
data(movielens)
library(dslabs)
```

**timestamp**

```
(Header)
(1) 1260759144 
(2) 1260759179 
(3) 1260759182 
(4) 1260759185
```

Trying to convert the (epoch time). to Proper date with time.

```
data(movielens)
lubridate as_datetime

2019-04-29 08:01
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(1260759179, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")` ?

Comment: I do not understand the format of your timestamp. Would you mind make it more explicit? Also, lubridate has yet many posts in SO, so please make sure your issue is not yet covered somewhere else (re-write your question few times with synonyms).

Comment: Load the movielens data frame from dslabs.

data(movielens)
This data frame contains a set of about 100,000 movie reviews. The timestamp column contains the review date as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 (epoch time).

Convert the timestamp column to dates using the lubridate as_datetime function.

Which year had the most movie reviews?

Comment: rating  timestamp (Headers)
1)      2.5 1260759144
2)      3.0 1260759179
3)      3.0 1260759182
4)      2.0 1260759185
5)      4.0 1260759205

Answer (score 1):

Using only `dplyr` and base R functions from time-manipulations we can convert the timestamp to `POSIXct` object, extract the year from it and count number of reviews for each year and `arrange` it in decreasing order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
data(movielens)

movielens %>%
   mutate(timestamp1 = as.POSIXct(timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), 
          year = format(timestamp1, "%Y")) %>%
   count(year) %>%
   arrange(desc(n))


# A tibble: 22 x 2
#   year      n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 2000  13869
# 2 2006   7493
# 3 2005   7161
# 4 2015   6610
# 5 1996   6239
# 6 2016   6225
# 7 1999   5901
# 8 2001   4658
# 9 2004   4658
#10 2003   4462
# … with 12 more rows
```

Or using `lubridate` functions

```
library(lubridate)
movielens %>%
   mutate(timestamp1 = as_datetime(timestamp),
          year = year(timestamp1)) %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   arrange(desc(n))
```